# What kind of car did Lij Samson Beyene crash?

Tags: 20th-century, death, ethiopia, automobiles, accidents

[*Lij*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_aristocratic_and_court_titles) Samson, a grandson of Haile Selassie, died at 28 or 29. According to biographer Haggai Erlich:

> In July 1963 one of his grandsons, Lij Samson, was killed. The prince drove recklessly after a night in Addis Ababa's bars and crashed his automobile.

His life is summed up in an [online genealogy](http://www.royalark.net/Ethiopia/shoa6.htm):

> *Dejazmatch* Samson Beyene. b. at Addis Ababa, 1934, educ. Columbia Univ, Ithaca, New York, USA. Taken to Italy and confined there by the Italians in 1936. Released and returned to Ethiopia 1943. Consul-General New York 1956-1959, Counselor Ethiopian legation Stockholm 1959-1960, Charges d’Affaires Stockholm 1960-1963. m. at Addis Ababa, 1959 Woizero Koremtit Andargatchew (b. at London, 3rd December 1939; m. second, Captain Haile Girmai, and d. at London, 29th December 2012, leaving further issue), daughter of H.E. Ras Andargatchew Masai, sometime Viceroy of Eritrea, by his first wife, Woizero Sergut. He was k. in a car crash, 10th July 1963, having had issue, an only son....

**In what model of car did he die?**

Comment: I had not realized that Columbia University was in Ithaca. That makes me a little suspicious of the extract.

Comment: @JonCuster Nice catch.

Comment: Samson Beyene _did_ attend Columbia, which has some material of/on/by him in its [archival photo collection](https://findingaids.library.columbia.edu/ead/nnc-ua/ldpd_4080179/dsc), and he _did_ die in a car crash on July 10, 1963. A very brief article on page 9 of the July 11, 1963 _Times_ headlined "Emperor's Nephew Killed in Crash" ("from our correspondent") and datelined Addis Ababa, July 10 reads: "Prince Samson Beyene, nephew [sic] of Emperor Hailé Selassie, was killed in a car accident early this morning. He was returning from Debrezeit, 30 miles from Addis Ababa." No further details.

Comment: But obviously Columbia is in NYC, not in Ithaca.

Comment: There may be something in the _Ethiopia Herald_ archives, if they exist. Surely the death of a member of the royal family should have made the news at least locally.

Answer (score 1):

It was a gold [Mercury Comet](https://i0.wp.com/www.macsmotorcitygarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/1960-Comet-rear-315.jpg?resize=584%2C307&ssl=1). I am not sure of the year but they only started making them in 1960. I know this for a fact because it was my parents' car. My mother and my great aunt were passengers when the prince lost consciousness, and control of the wheel. This is not widely known, but he was, in fact, poisoned... he was not driving recklessly as the article implies. My mother almost lost her life, and was hospitalized in Addis Ababa for quite a while.  Very shortly afterwards we returned to United States as a family.